# Magento Backend site not logging in

Tags: magento, mamp

After installing Magento on my localhost using mamp, I can't access the admin portal. I go to

```
http://localhost:8888/shop1/index.php/admin/
```

and then use my user and password and that's all. No error, no nothing, just the login admin panel.

What am I doing wrong?

NOTE: I also reinstalled 3 times and redownloaded the file to install Magento.

Thanks in advance for your help

UPDATE

---

This only happen on google chrome, safari and mozilla works slow but works.

UPDATE 2

---

I'm trying to reintall using 127.0.0.1 and using firefox and I get this exception:

> Mage_Core_Exception Object (
>       [_messages:protected] => Array
>           (
>           )
>
> ```
> [message:protected] => Can't retrieve entity config: sales/quote_shipping_rate
> [string:Exception:private] => 
> [code:protected] => 0
> [file:protected] => /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shop2/app/Mage.php
> [line:protected] => 594
> [trace:Exception:private] => Array
>     (
>         [0] => Array
>             (
>                 [file] => /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shop2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php
>                 [line] => 272
>                 [function] => throwException
>                 [class] => Mage
>                 [type] => ::
>                 [args] => Array
>                     (
>                         [0] => Can't retrieve entity config: sales/quote_shipping_rate
>                     )
>
>             )
>
>         [1] => Array
>             (
>                 [file] => /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shop2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
>                 [line] => 184
>                 [function] => getTableName
>                 [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource
>                 [type] => ->
>                 [args] => Array
>                     (
>                         [0] => sales/quote_shipping_rate
>                     )
>
>             )
>
>         [2] => Array
>             (
>                 [file] => /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shop2/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Setup.php
>                 [line] => 87
>                 [function] => getTable
>                 [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
>                 [type] => ->
>                 [args] => Array
>                     (
>                         [0] => sales/quote_shipping_rate
>                     )
>
>             )
>
>         [3] => Array
>             (
>                 [file] => /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shop2/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Setup.php
>                 [line] => 101
>                 [function] => _flatTableExist
>                 [class] => Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup
>                 [type] => ->
>                 [args] => Array
>                     (
>                         [0] => sales/quote_shipping_rate
>                     )
>
>             )
>
>         [4] => Array
>             (
>                 [file] => /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shop2/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.16-0.9.17.php
>                 [line] => 32
>                 [function] => addAttribute
>                 [class] => Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup
>                 [type] => ->
>                 [args] => Array
>                     (
>                         [0] => quote_address_rate
>                         [1] => method_title
>                         [2] => Array
>                             (
>                                 [type] => text
>                             )
>
>                     )
>
>             )
>
>         [5] => Array
>             (
>                 [file] => /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shop2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
>                 [line] => 624
>                 [args] => Array
>                     (
>                         [0] => /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shop2/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.16-0.9.17.php
>                     )
>
>                 [function] => include
>             )
>
>         [6] => Array
>             (
>                 [file] => /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shop2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
>                 [line] => 437
>                 [function] => _modifyResourceDb
>                 [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
>                 [type] => ->
>                 [args] => Array
>                     (
>                         [0] => upgrade
>                         [1] => 0.9.14
>                         [2] => 1.6.0.8
>                     )
>
>             )
>
>         [7] => Array
>             (
>                 [file] => /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shop2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
>                 [line] => 320
>                 [function] => _upgradeResourceDb
>                 [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
>                 [type] => ->
>                 [args] => Array
>                     (
>                         [0] => 0.9.14
>                         [1] => 1.6.0.8
>                     )
>
>             )
>
>         [8] => Array
>             (
>                 [file] => /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shop2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
>                 [line] => 235
>                 [function] => applyUpdates
>                 [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
>                 [type] => ->
>                 [args] => Array
>                     (
>                     )
>
>             )
>
>         [9] => Array
>             (
>                 [file] => /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shop2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php
>                 [line] => 417
>                 [function] => applyAllUpdates
>                 [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
>                 [type] => ::
>                 [args] => Array
>                     (
>                     )
>
>             )
>
>         [10] => Array
>             (
>                 [file] => /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shop2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php
>                 [line] => 343
>                 [function] => _initModules
>                 [class] => Mage_Core_Model_App
>                 [type] => ->
>                 [args] => Array
>                     (
>                     )
>
>             )
>
>         [11] => Array
>             (
>                 [file] => /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shop2/app/Mage.php
>                 [line] => 683
>                 [function] => run
>                 [class] => Mage_Core_Model_App
>                 [type] => ->
>                 [args] => Array
>                     (
>                         [0] => Array
>                             (
>                                 [scope_code] => 
>                                 [scope_type] => store
>                                 [options] => Array
>                                     (
>                                     )
>
>                             )
>
>                     )
>
>             )
>
>         [12] => Array
>             (
>                 [file] => /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shop2/index.php
>                 [line] => 87
>                 [function] => run
>                 [class] => Mage
>                 [type] => ::
>                 [args] => Array
>                     (
>                         [0] => 
>                         [1] => store
>                     )
>
>             )
>
>     )
>
> [previous:Exception:private] =>  )
> ```

Comment: As for your second edit, something is seriously wrong. Are you trying to install vanilla magento?

Comment: No, I'm trying to install the community version with the sample data

Comment: Vanilla as in stock, which you are, so it has to be a server configuration issue, reinstall mamp maybe?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to cookies not being set correctly when the domain is localhost.

Change it to 127.0.0.1 and it should work, will probably need another uninstall.